# How to loop Samplers with different intervals in same loop using JMeter

Tags: java, testing, jmeter

Idea is to loop requests independently, the thread will run for 20 minutes. One Sample will sample every 5 seconds. Other Samples in Simple controller will loop one by one with 10 second delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to run Samplers with different throughput within the bounds of one Thread Group because JMeter will always wait for the previous Sampler to complete before starting the next one.

The options are in:

1. Either move `/api-common/rest/rmslistterms` to a separate [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Or add the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) as a parent for the `/api-common/rest/rmslistterms` and configure it to run every 2nd iteration, example [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) you can use would be something like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3(${__jm__Loop Controller__idx} % 2 == 0,)}
   ```

   [image]